# Join two temp tables using SPARK SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am creating a temp table like below for one of my folder which is month=02. I want to Query for other folder which is month=03. I would like to know how can I do it. Shall i create two temp tables for each floder and then Join them. If yes can anyone help me with the Syntax. or if there is a way I can create a temp table in Spark for two folders.

This create one table sucessfully for month=02. I would like to query month=02 and month=03

```
df= spark.read.json("wasbs://container@storage.blob.core.windows.net/topics/details/year=2022/month=02/")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tableForFeb2022")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify below queries as per your requirements:

```
dF1.createOrReplaceTempView("tableForFeb2022")
dF2.createOrReplaceTempView("tableForMarch2022")

 spark.sql("select * from tableForFeb2022 tbl1, tableForMarch2022 tbl2 
    "where tbl1.id == tbl2.id ")
    .show(false)
```

Refer this [article](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-join-multiple-dataframes/) by NKK for more information

---

You can create two different dataframes, then combine them as given [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-union-and-union-all/) and finally create spark sql table.